# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<LightSwitchApplication.LettersSentItem>'

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

The table PatientsMaster has a relationship with LettersSentitem. In the letterssentitem table I have a field called lettertype. I have three different types of letters. How can I allow only type of letter from one patient.

```
  partial void DateSent_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
    { 
        if (this.PatientsMasterItem.LettersSentItem.Count() > 3 || this.PatientsMasterItem.LettersSentItem.Distinct(LetterType))
        {
        results.AddPropertyError("Can't Print More than 3 letters per patient");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have three types of letters, and a patient may send a maximum of three letters, but they all have to be of the same type? Is that what you wish to check?

Comment: they all have to be different type. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is more than one letter of the same type, and one way to do this is by grouping on `LetterType`, and checking `.Count()` for each of the results:

```
partial void DateSent_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
{ 
    if (this.PatientsMasterItem.LettersSentItem.GroupBy(i => i.LetterType).Any(l => l.Count() > 1))
    {
        results.AddPropertyError("Can't print more than one letter of the same type per patient");
    }
}
```

`.Distinct(x)` isn't going to work. `letters.Distinct(x)` selects all distinct letters (letting `x` decide which ones are equal), but if you drop any letters by using `Distinct()`, you no longer have the information you need to count.